# Enable landscape mode in QLPreviewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

In my iPhone application I am using QLPreviewController. How can I enable landscape mode for it?

Comment: follow this for ios 6 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758398/orientation-is-not-working-in-ios6/13758480#13758480

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below:

In "AppDelegate"

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

In your respective "ViewController" in which you have implement "QLPreviewController"

Add below:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    return YES;
else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    return YES;
else 
    return NO;
}
```

Hope, it will be helpful to you.

Cheers!

Comment: I use ios6 (there is a tag ios 6), I have tried it is doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in app delegate won't help. Create an extension of **`UIVieController , UITabbarController (if you are using one in your app)`** and override these two methods that **Nishant B** has provided you with there. These two are the two new apis added in iOS6.